# Error: 'geth' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: ethereum, geth

I want to run Ethereum private network on my  computer.[image] I already installed geth and also set the environment variable path but still geth is not recognised. Is it something worng with my pc or installation process.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed geth according to the instructions.

I recommend to try to set the paths as follows

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Select the System
3. Select Advance System Settings
4. In the open window of Advance System Setting click the Environment Variable button
5. In Environment Variable Window Select the Path Variable and press Edit Button
   Then Just simply Copy the path of your Geth Installation directory like below and Save "C:\Program Files (x86)\Geth"

I hope this helps.

Anyway, I recommend using linux for this stuff -> you'll avoid other problems of this type

Answer (score 0):

You have to take you geth path like my geth path is `C:\Program Files\Geth`, so to enter this is environment path like this `C:\Program Files\Geth\`